# The transition animation doesn't work after using a ListPicker element in full-screen mode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a separate page for a `ListPicker` element with property `ExpansionMode` set to `FullScreenOnly`.

If I don't use it - returning animation works fine, both `NavigationOutTransition` of the current page and `NavigationInTransition` of the destination page are shown properly. However, if I touch it and then somehow close it - the `NavigationOutTransition` is simply skipped.

I have a suspicion that this is happening because of the `Popup` in the `ListPicker` design, but I don't know what can and should I do about it. Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with your suspicion and I would say there is no solution worth pursuing to work around it.

Comment: Of course this is a barely-noticeable minor bug, but still. Software never is too polished :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say - try to hide the popup before the navigation happens - there should be some ways to achieve that - maybe just call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.Navigate(...)) to delay the navigation call and let you close the popup before the navigation occurs.

Comment: `Popup` is closed before the navigation occurs. Here are my steps: I tap `ListPicker` -> `Popup` pops up; I tap my choice -> `Popup` disappears; I click back-button -> at that moment `Popup` isn't in the `VisualTree`, but the animation fails. So, my guess is that `Popup` makes some changes to the parent page, is it opened or not.